# Connect to Facebook with Javascript Client Library using Adobe AIR

Tags: facebook, air, adobe

I'm having an issue connecting to Facebook through the Javascript Client Library in Adobe AIR. It works fine in the browser but in Adobe AIR it seems to not be able to find the Facebook functions. Here is some code I copied from the Facebook website: (Oh and I have the xd_receiver.htm file in the correct path too)

```
<textarea style="width: 1000px; height: 300px;" id="_traceTextBox">
</textarea>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

//

```
      var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;
      // require user to login 
      api.requireLogin(function(exception){
          FB.FBDebug.logLevel=1;
          FB.FBDebug.dump("Current user id is " + api.get_session().uid);
          // Get friends list 

         //5-14-09: this code below is broken, correct code follows 
         //api.friends_get(null, function(result){
         //     Debug.dump(result, 'friendsResult from non-batch execution ');
         // });

           api.friends_get(new Array(), function(result, exception){
                FB.FBDebug.dump(result, 'friendsResult from non-batch execution ');
           });
      });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple actually man, the problem with loading external script files from the application sandbox is that it's not supported. Technically, by using iframes, you should be able to do this and it works but it's still impossible to use XFBML in the root document after from my experience. After two days of trial and error, the easiest way to do use Facebook Connect in an html/ajax adobe air application is to download the actionscript library and include it as such:

```
<script type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="lib/facebook.swf"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var FB = window.runtime.com.facebook;
var fb = new FB.Facebook();
var session = new FB.utils.DesktopSessionHelper();
//etc...
</script>
```

then just refer to the documentation. my only problem now it that I still haven't found an efficient enough way of using XFBML in adobe air, simply adding the facebook namespace to the html tag doesn't do the trick unfortunately. If any knows, please do share thanks

Answer (score 0):

you also need to change xml namespace (main html tag) to this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
```

Comment: That didnt seem to work. When I run the application through adl it says, in the terminal, "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FB_RequireFeatures"